# how to return a string method in a class?

Tags: string, class, methods, numbers, format

here's some  code i got in python and i am stuck about how to print a string method in a class in python...please help out if you can...thnx a lot...

the code is below!

```
class Rat:
    """ A rat caught in a maze. """

    # Write your Rat methods here.
    def __init__(Rat, symbol, row, col):
        Rat.symbol = symbol
        Rat.row = row
        Rat.col = col

        num_sprouts_eaten = 0

    def set_location(Rat, row, col):

        Rat.row = row
        Rat.col = col

    def eat_sprout(Rat):
        num_sprouts_eaten += 1        

    def __str__(self):
        """ (Contact) -> str

        Return a string representation of this Rat.
        """
        result = 'To: '
        for contact in Rat.symbol:
            result = result + '{0}, '.format(Rat.symbol)

        result = result + '\nSubject: {0}'.format(Rat.row)
        result = result + '\n{0}'.format(Rat.col)
        return result
        #return '{0} {1} <{2}>'.format(Rat.symbol, 
         #   Rat.row, Rat.col)
```

I need to know how to return a string representation of the Rat!

Return a string representation of the rat, in this format:
symbol at (row, col) ate num_sprouts_eaten sprouts.

For example: 'J at (4, 3) ate 2 sprouts.'
Do not put a newline character ('\n') at the end of the string.

So how will I fix up the last method?

```
  def __str__(self):
            """ (Contact) -> str

            Return a string representation of this Rat.
            """
            result = 'To: '
            for contact in Rat.symbol:
                result = result + '{0}, '.format(Rat.symbol)

            result = result + '\nSubject: {0}'.format(Rat.row)
            result = result + '\n{0}'.format(Rat.col)
            return result
            #return '{0} {1} <{2}>'.format(Rat.symbol, 
             #   Rat.row, Rat.col)
```

It needs to print out something like the following: 'J at (4, 3) ate 2 sprouts.'  However with the code above, I get an error when I type print(object)...I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    print(a)
  File "C:\Users\gijoe\Downloads\a2.py", line 61, in __str__
    for contact in Rat.symbol:
AttributeError: class Rat has no attribute 'symbol'
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of the function represent the object itself, and defining

```
def __str__ (self):
```

you have called it `self`. So, to avoid the `AttributeError`, inside the `__str__` function you should substitute `Rat.symbol` in `self.symbol`.